# IE always in Quirks mode

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Following site i have build always load in quirks mode which then rise the box model bug for older IE.

[site](http://jstechstore.com.au/)

I have added the document type as xhtml1-strict.dtd and there is no white spaces or BOM characters. When i change the document mode to IE7 or IE8 standers from developer tools it shows the site correctly.

I have try to change the quirks mode loading in many ways but couldnt success. If you guys also dont know how to change to quirks mode loading i would appriciate if any hack to the alligment issue i am getting can be posted.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page starts exactly like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Lose *everything* before the DTD (including the blank lines before the xml declaration, which don't show correctly), and it should parse in standards mode.

Another solution is to use the `X-UA-Compatible` response header, like this:

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=8
```

(or IE=7, or IE=9)

Finally, please do read the [MSDN documentation on document compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- it's the definitive resource on the subject.

**Update:**

Since you are using PHP, and you have a spurious Unicode BOM in your source, it's almost certain that one or more of your PHP source files include a BOM. You need to save them **without a BOM and without any other characters before the `<?php` tag**.

To make sure you got them all, write a short program that opens up PHP files and reads the first byte. If it's not '<', then something is probably wrong.

Alternatively, you can use the `X-UA-Compatible` header as I mention above.

Comment: Jon..i have change the source but still it loads in quirks mode

Comment: @Harshana: I have updated the answer. Please read it *carefully*.

Answer (score 7):

View source and your first line of code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

You need `DOCTYPE` to be the very first line.

**Edit:** You've removed the `<?xml...>`, but you still have an issue.  Line 1 is blank but line 2 contains an invisible character - `U+FEFF` - the [unicode BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  You'll need to remove that.

Are you using Server-Side Includes or some other server technology that could be joining two files or otherwise adding to the response?

Comment: To be clear, what he is doing is perfectly valid and correct. As always, this is a long time issue with IE alone.

Comment: i have even try that..and i have now upload as doctype in the first line

Comment: @Harshana - You have `DOCTYPE` as the 3rd line, following two blank lines.  Try deleting those first two lines.

Comment: @Harshana, can you lose the the newlines and whitespace as well ?

Comment: @Harshana - In my testing, normal whitespace (ie, line breaks and space characters) before the doctype is fine.  However, you have one blank line, then on line two you have an invisible character, I would guess it's a unicode byte order marker.  If you get rid of that character it works.

Comment: thanks gilly and gaby..im my notepad++ i have delete all the blank lines above doc type..but when i view source i can also see some blank lines..is it possible

Comment: @gilly..i have agian save my html in notepade with encode in UTF with out BOM..ru still see the special character..btw which tool you use to see those characters..i dont see any in my notepad++

Comment: @Harshana - When viewing your source I noticed that I had to press my arrow key twice to get the cursor to move from line 2 to line 3.  You can actually copy that character from the view source window and paste it into a JavaScript console.  Running `"".charCodeAt(0)` (with the invisible character pasted in) returns 65279, which is indeed the Unicode BOM (U+FEFF).

Comment: thanks gilly..i have use X-UA-Compatible: IE=8 instead if doc type and it works.

Answer (score 2):

If a doctype that triggers strict mode is preceded by an xml prolog, the page shows in quirks mode.

It looks like the code output does.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
```

Comment: the specific issue with the xml prolog is about IE6 only.. but still all IEs if the first thing is not doctype  then they go in quirks..

Comment: Indeed, it was introduced in IE 6, but still relevant to all the other IEs out there. Thanks for bringing that up for completeness! :)